# Nuget auto linker for solution projects

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, nuget

While working in a solution that has projects building on top of each other, like

```
Lib1
Lib1.Sub1
Lib1.Sub1.Sub1
Lib1.Sub1.Sub2
Lib1.Sub2
etc.
```

is it possible to have, as an example, `Lib1.Sub1` reference `Lib1` directly (so on a solution level) but then when packing it, have it reference the nuget package instead? Because as it stands, packing it with nuget it will not recognize it has a dependency on `Lib1` because it's nuget package has not been referenced.

So then when I install `Lib1.Sub1` to a project via nuget, it won't automatically install `Lib1` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature you're requesting here will be available in NuGet v2.5 (which is planned to be released some time at the end of April I believe):

> When building a package from a project, when
>   -IncludeReferencedProjects is specified, projects  referenced by the project are either added as a dependency of the package, if nuspec
>   file exists, or are added into the package if nuspec file doesn't
>   exist.

See [changelog.txt](http://nuget.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/10d5d38151489ce053b314ed440bdbfbc30c595f#changelog.txt) for v2.5 for details.